# PHP: How to get value of radio button then use it in SQL statemet

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I get the value of my radio button and used it to my SQL statement. I created a script but not working :(

Expected result:

I want my dropdown dependent on the value of radio button

script:

```
<tr>
    <td><br><input type="radio" name="lockin"   value="1" checked /> Yes </td> 
    <td><br><input type="radio" name="lockin"   value="0"/>No    </td> 
</tr>

    <tr>
        <td   ><br>Reason for Disconnection</td>
            <td><br>
                <select id="reasondd"  name="R" onChange="change_reason()"  width="40" >

                <option id="mySelect" value="" selected="selected" >Select</option> 
                <?php 

                if(isset($_POST['lockin'])) {
                    if($_POST['value'] == 1) {
                $WhereC= 1;
                }   elseif($_POST['value'] == 0) {
                $WhereC=0;
                }}
                $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT discon_reason FROM note_gen2 where lock_in_stat = '$WhereC' order by discon_reason asc");  
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['discon_reason'];?>"><?php echo $row["discon_reason"]; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You need to make a network call using JavaScript to send the data to your PHP server (look into AJAX or for more modern browsers, `fetch`)

Comment: instead of using this `$_POST['value']` use `$_POST['R']`

Answer (score -1):

In this, there is no $WhereC.

$res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT discon_reason FROM note_gen2 where lock_in_stat = '$WhereC' order by discon_reason asc");

Comment: if(isset($_POST['lockin']))  <= if this is false condition, there is no variable for $WhereC. So you need include else condition for $WhereC